# Editing php file template doesn't take effect on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have been using a Wordpress template and I need to add one more input field as well as deleting two others. This is a file to submit and go to checking before going public.

I went to source file of the template and the submit file and to the template file, and commenting out the lines where those input fields are.

But IT DOESN'T TAKE EFFECT on the page. I inspect over and over the page and nothing is changed. Not even if add or delete other parts of the file and the html tags.

I used the css display:none for not to show, but I need to add one more input and anything that I do this file seems to take effect.

I really don't understand why. Is it better if I use Javascript and create the inner HTML? But how can I get it in the email after submiting?

If you can help me in any way, please!!

```
<?php
/*
 *  Edit Form
 */

global $inspiry_options;
$edit_property_id = intval( trim( $_GET['edit_property'] ) );
$target_property = get_post( $edit_property_id );

// check if passed id is a proper property post */
if ( !empty( $target_property ) && ( $target_property->post_type == 'property' ) ) {

    // Check Author
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // check if current user is the author of property
    if ( $target_property->post_author == $current_user->ID ) {

        $property_meta = get_post_custom( $target_property->ID );
        ?>
        <form id="submit-property-form" class="submit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    

            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-6">    
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="inspiry_property_title"><?php _e('Property Title', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input id="inspiry_property_title" name="inspiry_property_title" type="text" class="required" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $target_property->post_title ); ?>" title="<?php _e('* Please provide property title!', 'inspiry'); ?>" autofocus required/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="description"><?php _e('Property Description', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5"><?php echo esc_textarea( $target_property->post_content ); ?></textarea>
                    </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="form-option">
                        <?php
                        $property_address = "";
                        if ( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_address'] ) && ! empty ( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_address'][0] ) ) {
                            $property_address = $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_address'][0];
                        } else {
                            $property_address = $inspiry_options[ 'inspiry_submit_address' ];
                        }

                        $property_location = "";
                        if ( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_location'] ) && ! empty ( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_location'][0] ) ) {
                            $property_location = $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_location'][0];
                        } else {
                            $property_location = $inspiry_options[ 'inspiry_submit_location_coordinates' ];
                        }
                        ?>
                        <label for="address"><?php _e('Address', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="required" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $property_address ); ?>" title="<?php _e( '* Please provide a property address!', 'inspiry'); ?>" required/>
                        <div class="map-wrapper">
                            <button class="btn-default goto-address-button" type="button" value="address"><?php _e('Find Address', 'inspiry'); ?></button>
                            <div class="map-canvas"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="location" class="map-coordinate" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $property_location ); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>    
            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="type"><?php _e('Type', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <select name="type" id="type" class="search-select">
                            <?php inspiry_hierarchical_edit_options( $target_property->ID, 'property-type' ); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="city"><?php _e('Location', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <select name="city" id="city" class="search-select">
                            <?php inspiry_hierarchical_edit_options( $target_property->ID, 'property-city' ); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="status"><?php _e('Status', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <select name="status" id="status" class="search-select">
                            <?php inspiry_hierarchical_edit_options( $target_property->ID, 'property-status' ); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="bedrooms"><?php _e('Bedrooms', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input id="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" type="text" value="<?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $property_meta[ 'REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms' ][0] ); } ?>" title="<?php _e('* Only numbers allowed!', 'inspiry'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="bathrooms"><?php _e('Bathrooms', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input id="bathrooms" name="bathrooms" type="text" value="<?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $property_meta[ 'REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms' ][0] ); } ?>" title="<?php _e('* Only numbers allowed!', 'inspiry'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="garages"><?php _e('Garages', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input id="garages" name="garages" type="text" value="<?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_garage'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_garage'][0] ); } ?>" title="<?php _e('* Only numbers allowed!', 'inspiry'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="price"><?php _e('Sale OR Rent Price', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input id="price" name="price" type="text" value="<?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_price'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_price'][0] ); } ?>" title="<?php _e('* Only numbers allowed!', 'inspiry'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>                  

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="size"><?php _e( 'Area', 'inspiry' ); ?></label>
                        <input id="size" name="size" type="text" value="<?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_size'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_size'][0] ); } ?>" title="<?php _e('* Only numbers allowed!', 'inspiry'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>                  

            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

            <div class="row">                 

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="property-id"><?php _e('Property ID', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input id="property-id" name="property-id" type="text"  value="<?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_id'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_property_id'][0] ); } ?>" title="<?php _e('Property ID', 'inspiry'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label for="video-url"><?php _e('Virtual Tour Video URL', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <input id="video-url" name="video-url" type="text" value="<?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_tour_video_url'] ) ) { echo esc_attr( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_tour_video_url'][0] ); } ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

            <div class="row container-row">

                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="form-option">
                        <div id="gallery-thumbs-container" class="clearfix">
                            <?php
                            $thumbnail_size = 'thumbnail';
                            $properties_images = rwmb_meta( 'REAL_HOMES_property_images', 'type=plupload_image&size='.$thumbnail_size, $target_property->ID );
                            $featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $target_property->ID );
                            if( !empty( $properties_images ) ){
                                foreach( $properties_images as $prop_image_id => $prop_image_meta ) {
                                    $is_featured_image =  ( $featured_image_id == $prop_image_id );
                                    $featured_icon = ( $is_featured_image ) ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o';
                                    echo '<div class="gallery-thumb">';
                                    echo '<img src="'.$prop_image_meta['url'].'" alt="'.$prop_image_meta['title'].'" />';
                                    echo '<a class="remove-image" data-property-id="'.$target_property->ID.'" data-attachment-id="' . $prop_image_id . '" href="#remove-image" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                                    echo '<a class="mark-featured" data-property-id="'.$target_property->ID.'" data-attachment-id="' . $prop_image_id . '" href="#mark-featured" ><i class="fa '. $featured_icon . '"></i></a>';
                                    echo '<span class="loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>';
                                    echo '<input type="hidden" class="gallery-image-id" name="gallery_image_ids[]" value="' . $prop_image_id . '"/>';
                                    if ( $is_featured_image ) {
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" class="featured-img-id" name="featured_image_id" value="' . $prop_image_id . '"/>';
                                    }
                                    echo '</div>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div id="drag-and-drop">
                            <div class="drag-drop-msg text-center">
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php _e('Drag and drop images here', 'inspiry'); ?>
                                <br/>
                                <span class="drag-or"><?php _e('OR', 'inspiry'); ?></span>
                                <br/>
                                <a id="select-images" class="drag-btn btn-default btn-orange" href="javascript:;"><?php _e('Select Images', 'inspiry'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="field-description list-unstyled">
                            <li><span>*</span><?php _e('An image should have minimum width of 850px and minimum height of 600px.', 'inspiry'); ?></li>
                            <li><span>*</span><?php _e('You can mark an image as featured by clicking the star icon, Otherwise first image will be considered featured image.', 'inspiry'); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="plupload-container"></div>
                        <div id="errors-log"></div>
                    </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label class="fancy-title"><?php _e('What to display in agent information box ?', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <ul class="agent-options list-unstyled">

                            <li>
                                <span class="radio-field">
                                    <input id="agent_option_none" type="radio" name="agent_display_option" value="none" <?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option'] ) && ( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option'][0] == "none" ) ) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
                                    <label for="agent_option_none"><?php _e('None', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                                </span>
                                <small><?php _e('( Agent information box will not be displayed )', 'inspiry'); ?></small>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span class="radio-field">
                                    <input id="agent_option_profile" type="radio" name="agent_display_option" value="my_profile_info" <?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option'] ) && ( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option'][0] == "my_profile_info" ) ) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
                                    <label for="agent_option_profile"><?php _e('My Profile Information', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                                </span>
                                <?php
                                if( !empty( $inspiry_options[ 'inspiry_edit_profile_page' ] ) ) {
                                    $edit_profile_url = get_permalink( $inspiry_options[ 'inspiry_edit_profile_page' ] );
                                    if ( !empty( $edit_profile_url ) ) {
                                        ?>
                                        <small>
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $edit_profile_url ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e('( Edit Profile Information )', 'inspiry'); ?></a>
                                        </small>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span class="radio-field">
                                    <input id="agent_option_agent" type="radio" name="agent_display_option" value="agent_info" <?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option'] ) && ( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option'][0] == "agent_info" ) ) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
                                    <label for="agent_option_agent"><?php _e( 'Display Agent Information', 'inspiry' ); ?></label>
                                </span>
                                <select name="agent_id" id="agent-selectbox">
                                    <?php
                                    if ( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agents'] ) ) {
                                        inspiry_generate_cpt_options( 'agent', $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_agents'][0] );
                                    } else {
                                        inspiry_generate_cpt_options( 'agent' );
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-option checkbox-option clearfix">
                        <input id="featured" name="featured" type="checkbox" <?php if( isset( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_featured'] ) && ( $property_meta['REAL_HOMES_featured'][0] == 1 ) ) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
                        <label for="featured"><?php _e('Mark this property as featured property', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

            <div class="row container-row">

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-option">
                        <label class="fancy-title"><?php _e('Features', 'inspiry'); ?></label>
                        <ul class="features-checkboxes-wrapper list-unstyled clearfix">
                            <?php
                            // Property Features
                            $property_features = get_the_terms( $target_property->ID, "property-feature" );
                            $property_features_ids = array();
                            if ( !empty( $property_features ) && !is_wp_error( $property_features ) ) {
                                foreach( $property_features as $feature ) {
                                    $property_features_ids[] = $feature->term_id;
                                }
                            }

                            // All Features
                            $all_features = get_terms(
                                array(
                                    "property-feature"
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'orderby'       => 'name',
                                    'order'         => 'ASC',
                                    'hide_empty'    => false,
                                )
                            );

                            if ( !empty( $all_features ) && !is_wp_error( $all_features ) ) {
                                foreach ( $all_features as $feature ) {
                                    echo '<li><span class="option-set">';
                                    if( in_array( $feature->term_id, $property_features_ids ) ){
                                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="features[]" id="feature-' . $feature->term_id . '" value="' . $feature->term_id . '" checked />';
                                    }else{
                                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="features[]" id="feature-' . $feature->term_id . '" value="' . $feature->term_id . '" />';
                                    }
                                    echo '<label for="feature-' . $feature->term_id . '">' . $feature->name . '</label>';
                                    echo '</li>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="form-option">

                        <div class="inspiry-details-wrapper">

                            <label><?php _e( 'Additional Details', 'inspiry' ); ?></label>

                            <div class="inspiry-detail labels clearfix">
                                <div class="inspiry-detail-control">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="inspiry-detail-title"><label><?php _e( 'Title','inspiry' ) ?></label></div>
                                <div class="inspiry-detail-value"><label><?php _e( 'Value','inspiry' ); ?></label></div>
                                <div class="inspiry-detail-control">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- additional details container -->
                            <div id="inspiry-additional-details-container">

                                <?php
                                // output existing details
                                $additional_details = get_post_meta( $target_property->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_additional_details', true );

                                if( ! empty ( $additional_details ) ) {

                                    foreach( $additional_details as $title => $value ) {
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="inspiry-detail inputs clearfix">
                                            <div class="inspiry-detail-control">
                                                <i class="sort-detail fa fa-bars"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inspiry-detail-title">
                                                <input type="text" name="detail-titles[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inspiry-detail-value">
                                                <input type="text" name="detail-values[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inspiry-detail-control">
                                                <a class="remove-detail" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="inspiry-detail inputs clearfix">
                                        <div class="inspiry-detail-control">
                                            <i class="sort-detail fa fa-bars"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="inspiry-detail-title">
                                            <input type="text" name="detail-titles[]" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="inspiry-detail-value">
                                            <input type="text" name="detail-values[]" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="inspiry-detail-control">
                                            <a class="remove-detail" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>

                            </div><!-- end of additional details container -->

                            <div class="inspiry-detail clearfix">
                                <div class="inspiry-detail-control">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="inspiry-detail-control">
                                    <a class="add-detail" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>    
                    </div>    
                </div>    
            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

            <div class="row container-row">

                <div class="col-xs-12">

                    <div class="form-option">
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'submit_property', 'property_nonce' ); ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_property"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="property_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $target_property->ID ); ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Update Property', 'inspiry'); ?>" class="btn-small btn-orange"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="message-container"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

        </form>
        <?php

    } else {
        inspiry_message( __( 'Oops','inspiry' ), __( 'It appears that, Provided property does not belong to you!', 'inspiry' ) );
    }

    } else {
        inspiry_message( __( 'Oops','inspiry' ), __( 'It appears that, Provided property id is invalid!', 'inspiry' ) );
    }
```

Comment: What is the path/name of the file you are editing? You have selected this template in the post editor?

Comment: The path of this "edit-form.php" file is: /Users/Sevilla/Desktop/Sitios/DeNEgocios2/wp-content/themes/inspiry-real-places-child/partials/property/templates    It comes selected but I have even changed the path with another file but it doesn't change at all.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].  There is way too much stuff here to expect anyone to wade through it all.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a caching issue either browser or server side. Most likely server cache.

Clear browser cache by pressing ctrl+shift+r for PC.

If your web host uses a caching plugin you can try clearing the cache through the plugin interface in wp-admin.  (I recommend disabling caching plugins during development.)

If that doesn't work and you have access to cPanel or whatever your host uses for backend there should be a way to do a "master flush" of the cache.

Either that or you aren't actually editing the correct template. Sometimes theme files will override the core files and it can be tricky to find the correct file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have test it in my MAMP's localhost before changing the file on the webpage, and Since It wasn't working I gave it a try on the website after deleting the cache and even trying in  another browser. But nothing had work. I don't really know how to make a master flush in MAMP or server but I can ask them. I'm starting to think it may not be the template or something in the theme code is not allowing edits

Comment: Hi, I finally know what's happening, althought I'm not really sure If I can use this solution: I checked the Cache Wordpress(wp-cache) files, and everything were exactly the same as before changing the files. And while I edit this wp-cache file it's when takes effect on the page. I dont know if it's a good a idea to do it this way.

Comment: I don't think editing the cache file is a good idea. At some point the server will update the cache files from the templates and you will lose your changes.

It would be better to just manually delete the cache files if you can't find where to clear the cache through plugin or cPanel. Then your changes to template files should show up.